# Why Am I getting this erroor : "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute"

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to make a reusable input component but I'm getting this error on the console.  "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute".

**this is my signup class file:**
......

```
 authForm = new FormGroup(
    {
      username: new FormControl(
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.maxLength(20),
          Validators.pattern(/[⌃a-z0-9]+$/),
        ],
   ......
```

**this is my signup template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="authForm" class="ui form">
    <app-input
      label="Username"
      [control]="authForm.get('username')"
    ></app-input>

  .......
```

**this is my input class file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css'],
})

export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  constructor() {}
```

.......

**And this is my input template file:**

```
<label>{{ label }}</label>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="control" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to make a reusable form component, look up Angular ControlValueAccessor. you will need to use this interface to create a reusable form component